# How do I merge dictionaries having similar values in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have a problem.

```json
Input=[
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'mem','point':[{'second':0,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':5},
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':10,'severity':'warning'}],'date':'2021-09-13','PO':3},
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':20,'severity':'critical'}],'date':'2021-09-14','PO':3},
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':30,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':3}]
```

I will compare in this array. If the same name, I will combine all value of this dict.

It mean combine all value of key 'point'. I will have key list 'point' with multi dict

We have many duplicate key name = 'cpu'. So I will combine all value if the same value.U see we have PO the same value (PO=3 with name=cpu).If different value, we will take the last value(last value 'date':'2021-09-15').Finally, we will append the dicts in the key point list together

**Desired result**

```json
Output=[
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'mem','point':[{'second':0,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':5},
{'id':uuid1(),'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':10,'severity':'warning'},
                                    {'second':20,'severity':'critical'},
                                    {'second':30,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':3}
      ]
```

Note: I use python 3.6

I hope someone will help me. Thank you very muck

Comment: What are you trying to combine the dictionary over?? Can you explain `We have many duplicate key name = 'cpu'. So I will combine all value if the same value.U see we have PO the same value (PO=3 with name=cpu).If different value, we will take the last value(last value 'date':'2021-09-15').Finally, we will append the dicts in the key point list togethe` properly? its not very clear. Maybe given an example?

Comment: Hi Akshay. I'll expland: if duplicate key name. We'll combine value. key point += value in each point of dict. And date'll get last value with this key name (get  'date':'2021-09-15')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this but the following works:

```py
a=[{'name':'mem','point':[{'second':0,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':5},
{'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':10,'severity':'warning'}],'date':'2021-09-13','PO':3},
{'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':20,'severity':'critical'}],'date':'2021-09-14','PO':3},
{'name':'cpu','point':[{'second':30,'severity':'infor'}],'date':'2021-09-15','PO':3}]

b=[]
    
for i in a:
    for j in b: 
        if i['name'] == j['name']:
            j['point'] += i['point']
            break
    else:
        b.append(i)
```

Comment: It's so simple that I can't think of it. Thanks u ^^